# Manually setting the ID

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a Users table where the "ID" field is a GUID field.

Using ASPNET I am creating a user account and getting the GUID back.  I am trying to create associated records in my tables with that GUID as the main ID.

The problem I am running into is that when I manually set Users.ID NHibernate tries to do an Update, not an Insert.  I see this with the NHibernate Profiler before it bombs out with "Unexpected row count: 0; Expected: 1".

My UsersMap for the table Users looks like:

```
public class UsersMap : ClassMap<Users>
{
    public UsersMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.ID, "ID"); //GUID

        Map(x => x.Name, "Name"); //string
        Map(x => x.PhoneNumber, "PhoneNumber"); //string
        Map(x => x.FaxNumber, "FaxNumber"); //string
        Map(x => x.EmailAddress, "EmailAddress"); //string

        HasMany<UsersAddressBook>(x => x.usersAddressBook).KeyColumn("ID");
    }
}
```

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to specify that your id will be *assigned*.

```
Id(x => x.ID)
  .GeneratedBy.Assigned();
```

This will allow you to specify the value, without NHibernate trying to perform an update.

Comment: This appears to be the best method.  It also works perfectly.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

ISession.Save has an overload that allows you to specify identifier. Try using it, and don't set your id property manually.

Answer (score 0):

As added value to James's answer I used:

```
Id(x => x.ID)
  .GeneratedBy.Assigned()
  .UnsavedValue(default_value);
```

Note that default_value is default value for your Id type
as in me is `0L` because I use `long` for my Id